# how to display 0 while count in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple count query like this

```
SELECT BILLDATE,COUNT(BILLDATE) AS CNT 
FROM BILLS 
WHERE BILLDATE >='08/01/2013' AND    BILLDATE<='09/09/2013'  GROUP BY BILLDATE
```

it should display

```
billdate    cnt
01/09/2013   10
02/09/2013    0
03/09/2013    3
```

but I am getting

```
billdate    cnt
01/09/2013   10
03/09/2013    3
```

How to write the query?

Comment: SQL Server? PostgreSQL? MySQL?

Comment: You probably don't have a record for the `02/09/2013` date, and you would like to show the count anyway. Is this true?

Comment: Usually..it will return those count>1 , which means that record is not present

Answer (score 3):

That's because you have no records in `BILLS` for `BILLDATE = '2013-09-02'` (I suppose that `WHERE BILLDATE >='08/01/2013' AND    BILLDATE<='09/09/2013'` is a typo and you wanted to write `WHERE BILLDATE >='01/09/2013' AND    BILLDATE<='03/09/2013'`

There're many DB specific methods to make your query, but I think if you have to do this types of query often, the best way to go is to create static `DATES` table, populate it with dates (from, for example `1900-01-01` till `3000-01-01`):

```
Date
1900-01-01
1900-01-02
1900-01-03
...
2010-01-01
...
```

and use it like:

```
select
    d.DATE,
    count(b.BILLDATE) as cnt
from DATES as d
    left outer join BILLS as b on b.BILLDATE = d.DATE
where d.DATE >='2013-09-01' and d.DATE <= '2013-09-03'
group by d.DATE
```

Note also [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for dates.

If you don't care much about performance, you can use [recursive common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
with cte([Date]) as (
    select convert(date, '20130901', 112) -- Start date
    union all
    select dateadd(dd, 1, [Date])
    from cte
    where [Date] < '20130903'             -- End date
)
select
    c.[Date],
    count(b.BILLDATE) as cnt
from cte as c
    left outer join BILLS as b on b.BILLDATE = d.DATE
```

Comment: hi roman i didnt get for simple count its working but i need 0 in case there is no records how can i do this

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Do you care about performance or you have only a few rows for which you want to do this query?

Comment: sql server for few rows only for one report i need this

Comment: @user1702346 if you have to go this queries often you can create table , for example, Enumerable_Dates (or call it whatever you want) and fill it with Dates from 1900-01-01 till some large date, 9999-12-31.

Comment: i am created table and give frdate data 01/01/1900 and to date as 31/12/9999 and my query is select
    b.billDATE,
    count(b.BILLDATE) as cnt
from DATES as d
    left outer join BILLS as b on b.BILLDATE = d.frDATE
where b.billDATE >='08/01/2013' and b.billDATE <= '09/03/2013'
group by b.billDATE but not giving output

Comment: no, you have to select d.frDate instead of BillDate, and use d.frDate in where clause - see my first query. Use BillDate only inside count

Comment: ya i tried like this select
   d.frDATE,
    count(b.BILLDATE) as cnt
from DATES as d
    left outer join BILLS as b on b.BILLDATE = d.frDATE
where d.frDATE >='08/01/2013' and d.frDATE <= '09/03/2013'
group by d.frDATE but again same nothing is displayed. wats wrong in my query please help me

Comment: @user1702346 please don't use mm/dd/yyyy format for date. Use yyyymmdd or yyyy-mm-dd format and you'll be happy forever

Comment: i tried roman in both cases but i am getting no output wats wrong in my query select
   d.frDATE,
    count(b.BILLDATE) as cnt
from DATES as d
    left outer join BILLS as b on b.BILLDATE = d.frDATE
where d.frDATE >='2013-08-01' and d.frDATE <= '2013-09-01'
group by d.frDATE

Comment: unfortunately, sqlfiddle.com is not working now, could you create an example of your data later? this query should work